# Saving (and loading) a scikit-learn Keras Classifier

Tags: keras, scikit-learn, pickle

I am using the sklearn wrapper for a gridsearchCV hyperparameter optimization. I want to save the best model (in absolutely any file format that works) and maybe some metrics that the grid search returned. I have seen multiple threads about saving models from Keras and also models from scikit-learn but not as many on saving keras models that have been wrapped for sci-kit-learn.

I have tried using `gscv.best_estimator_.model.save('BestNN.h5')`

as suggested on [this thread](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/4274) but I could not find how to load this back (using `keras.models.load_model` returns an error).

Is there a simple way to save the wrapped classifier? Neither pickle, dill, joblib, or the method above seems to work. Here is some sample code (my gridsearch object is called gscv):

```
gscv.best_estimator_.model.save('BestNN.h5')
```

however, while the code abode does save an .h5 file, loading returns an error

```
from keras.models import load_model
load_model('BestNN.h5')
```

> File
> "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\envs\CondaPython37\lib\site-packages\keras\utils\generic_utils.py",
> line 140, in deserialize_keras_object
> ': ' + class_name)
>
> ValueError: Unknown initializer: GlorotUniform

Comment: Are you loading the model in a machine (or environment) different than the one in which you saved it?

Comment: No I am loading the model in the exact same environment.